# Is $(x_1,x_2) \mapsto \frac{x_1}{a-x_2}+b$ convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, rational-functions, hessian-matrix

I encountered the following objective function:

$$D(x_1,x_2) = \frac{x_1}{a-x_2}+b$$

Is it convex? If I use the Hessian to determine its convexity, I have

$$H = \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0  \\
       1 & \frac{2x_1}{(a-x_2)^3}  \\
      \end{bmatrix}$$

but the determinant of $H$ is zero, so we can't determine its convexity by using the Hessian value, right? So, how can we do? Thanks for any comment.

Comment: The Hessians enjoy of a symmetric look.  Revise the calculations.

Comment: oops, I see, I even have the hessian calculation wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Think of $x \mapsto \frac1x$. Is it convex? If the domain is $\mathbb R^+$, I would say it kind of is.